# ADD event to calender

Tags: objective-c

I'm using the following code:

```
//create instance of EKEventStore
            EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

            //creating instance of EKEvent
            EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];

            //setting the appropriate properties of the new event
            event.title     = @"England";

            event.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];


            event.endDate   = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:600
                                                         sinceDate:event.startDate];
            event.location = @"Metalist";
            event.notes = @" Play";


            [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
            NSError *error;
            [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
```

i want to save this data in:

9 june 2012 - 18:00  hour how can i do this?

```
event.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
event.endDate   = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:600 sinceDate:event.startDate];
```

And i want to make a warning (alert) too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an `NSDate` object with a specific date, you can use the `NSDateComponents` class:

```
NSDateComponents *myDate = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[myDate setDay:9];
[myDate setMonth:6];
[myDate setYear:2011];
[myDate setHour:18];
event.startDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:myDate];
```

Don't forget to release `myDate` if you are not using ARC:

```
[myDate release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSDateFormatter:

```
NSString *string = @"9 June 2012 - 18:00";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy - HH:mm"];

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:string];

[formatter release];
```